# IoT OS installing on top of Linux?

Tags: ubuntu-core

I am new in the field of IoT OS and I saw TinyOS, Conitki etc. can be installed on top of Ubuntu. Its not clear to me how these OSes are able to run on top of Ubuntu without any Hypervisor? Can someone explain whats going on here?

Is ubuntu working as virtual hardware for these OSes without Hypervisor?
How kernels of TinyOS or Conitki are interacting with programs?

Comment: Welcome! There are multiple different ways of running other distros on top of Ubuntu... you would have to tell us where you saw this, and furthurmore, I'm not too clear on how this is related to IoT.  Please [edit] your question to detail what exactly you're trying to do, what research you've done so far, and what you don't understand.  Thanks!

Comment: I’m not familiar with either, but a cursory search hasn’t shown me anyway to “install” either over Ubuntu. I’ve seen ways to build over Ubuntu, and of course you could use any virtualisation environnement to run them as a guest OS over Ubuntu, though... can you point out where you’ve seen any description of either being “installed over Ubuntu”?